# URL field in sharepoint : Points to Control Template when http removed

Tags: 2010, web-part, visual-studio, visual-web-part, url

We have a requirement to display urls based on logged in user . We created a single line of text for url storage in SharePoint list. C# code pulls the data and displays correctly . 
All is well when i display url "`http://www.google.com`"

But I have a issue when url in list says `"www.google.com"` i.e without `'http://'`
The URL is pointed to `_CONTROLTEMPLATES/mywebparts/visualwp/www.google.com` . What is the easiest workaround/solution for this ?

Comment: The most simple straight forward answer would be to just do something [like this with `UriBuilder`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5289768). But I suspect you have thought about this since you ask?

Comment: I checked the same .